# 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not able to execute it

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio, npm, npm-install

I have cloned a git repository it's an Angular 7 & .NET Core app, everything is fine in the project but when I try to restore npm packages I get the following error.

> \Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.EXE submodule
> update - q --init --recursive
> fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not
> able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
> npm ERR! cb() never called!

#Package.json

```
{
 "name": "name",
 "version": "6.1.1",
 "license": "......",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve --open",
   "start-hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr -sm=false",
   "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
   "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
   "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
   "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
   "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e",
   "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
  "@angular/animations": "6.0.5",
  "@angular/cdk": "6.2.1",
  "@angular/common": "6.0.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "6.0.5",
  "@angular/core": "6.0.5" 
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.8",
  "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.5",
  "@angular/language-service": "6.0.5",
  "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",  
  "typescript": "2.7.2",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.13.1"
  }
}
```

My installed `node-version` is `10.7.0` and `npm-version` is `6.4.1`

I found on GitHub some issues like this and they added a fix in npm-lifecycle, so I installed the `npm-lifecycle` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but in the command you pasted there is a space inside the '-q' option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `submodule` command is not built into the base `git.exe` binary, it is implemented as a shell script named `git-submodule`, which needs to be accessible from the `%PATH%`, and to be executable for the user who runs the action.

- What is your `%PATH%` (or the `%PATH%` for your npm process) ?
- Does it include the path to your git installation, which seems to be somewhere in `\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\` ?
- Does the user which runs the npm process have execution rights on `git-submodule` ?

Comment: to view your PATH env variable : `echo %PATH%`

Comment: On windows, you should point to "bin" subfolder. For example, in my case it was "C:\Program Files\Git\bin"

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) will fix a possible cause for this error message, seen on Windows.

See [commit 4e1a641](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e1a641ee345bbc877ed82962e12c45f09b6617b) (24 Aug 2019) by [Adam Roben (`aroben`)](https://github.com/aroben).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6f21347](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f21347f118f6c0c49d10485aa4bc1daaddee303), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: fix launching of externals from Unicode paths
>
> **If Git were installed in a path containing non-ASCII characters**,
>   commands such as `git am` and `git submodule`, which are implemented as
>   externals, would fail to launch with the following error:
>
> ```
> fatal: 'am' appears to be a git command, but we were not able to execute it.  
> Maybe git-am is broken?
> ```
>
> This was due to `lookup_prog` not being Unicode-aware. It was somehow
>   missed in [85faec9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85faec9d3acd8bb20e26e2d3386f7d3708d02fca) (Win32: Unicode file name support (except `dirent`),
>   2012-03-15, Git v2.1.0-rc0).
>
> Note that the only problem in this function was calling
>   `GetFileAttributes()` instead of `GetFileAttributesW()`.
>   The calls to `access()` were fine because `access()` is a macro which resolves to
>   `mingw_access()`, which already handles Unicode correctly.
>   But `lookup_prog()` was changed to use `_waccess()` directly so that we only
>   convert the path to UTF-16 once.
>
> To make things work correctly, we have to maintain UTF-8 and UTF-16 versions in tandem in `lookup_prog()`.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't have Git for windows installed. What I did, and it seems to have worked for me, is to open the visual studio installer, then choose to "modify" the current installation and from "Individual Components" tab I checked "Git for Windows" (which was not checked).

After the installation I did not get the same error again.

Comment: of course I had Git installed probably you didn't read question well, First 6 word  of the question is my answer for your answer and actually  the problem was path related. :)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it seems the 'git.exe' of cygin be called other than git of windows on Windows 10. Move 'C:\cygwin64\bin' to the end of PATH to make sure it after the 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin' path can solve this issue.