# How to get CMake's ExternalProject_Add to work in Visual Studio (git-submodule problem)?

Tags: git, cmake, visual-studio-2017, git-submodules

I am trying to build [Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin) to build directly on Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2017.
Pangolin's CMake involves the following command:

```
ExternalProject_Add( __glew
  PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glew"
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Perlmint/glew-cmake.git
  GIT_TAG 7574ab4d00b683e56adbfdec7da636529dfe65d8
  INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
             -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
             -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}
             -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}
             -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}
             -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}
)
```

When this code is run, I get the following error:

```
fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?
```

My analysis shows that this happens during the execution of the following generated CMake code (from `build-dir/external/glew/tmp/__glew-gitclone.cmake`):

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe"  submodule update --recursive --init 
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "C:/Users/scrambledusername/Garage/Pangolin/build/external/glew/src/__glew"
  RESULT_VARIABLE error_code
  )
if(error_code)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to update submodules in: 'C:/Users/scrambledusername/Garage/Pangolin/build/external/glew/src/__glew'")
endif()
```

In other words, the command `git submodule update --recursive --init` results in an error. However, it does not result in an error when run manually via Git Bash.

Some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672008/submodule-appears-to-be-a-git-command-but-we-were-not-able-to-execute-it) (also [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20815) in the related commits and [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-March/062896.html)) shows this may be related to either the git path or the path with the git-submodule script (`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` for me) should be added to system path. Prepending these to the system path (for system OR user) didn't affect the outcome (restarted system, VS just to make sure new paths were registered). I also made sure to the best of my abilities that the script file itself has run permissions for any user (are there caveats to this?).

Copy/pasted from cmd:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;C\Program Files\...
```

Does anyone know how to get this working or have any suggestions?

Current workaround: set `BUILD_EXTERN_GLEW=OFF` in CMake and manually check out and build the version of GLEW Pangolin needs based on its CMake.

Versions:

- git 2.23.0.windows.1
- VisualStudio Community 2017 15.9.16
- CMake 3.15.3
- Pangolin 25159034e62011b3527228e476cec51f08e87602 (latest commit to master at time of writing)

[EDIT (additional info)]

1. I got the same results when running cmake from Git Bash, command
   prompt, or via CMake-gui.
2. I got a perfect build on another machine with older
   versions of both Git and CMake.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around this problem by running cmake from normal command prompt instead of git bash. Seems like git bash produces non-ascii paths which causes some git commands to fail. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192041 - hopefully gets fixed in git 2.24)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, hopefully it helps someone. Unfortunately, in my case, running CMake from git bash, command prompt, or git-gui yields the same error when I try to build the external projects in VS 2017.

Comment: Yes. This. This is exactly what worked for me. FSCK VISUAL STUUDIO.